# How to check if Ant is executed under certain path?

Tags: ant

How can I use Ant to verify that the current working directory is located (arbitrarily deeply nested) under a certain path? For example, I want to execute a target only if the current directory is part of `/some/dir/`, for example if Ant is executed in directory `/some/dir/to/my/project/`.

The best I could come up with is a String contains condition:

```
<if>
    <contains string="${basedir}" substring="/some/dir/"/>
    <then>
        <echo>Execute!</echo>
    </then>
    <else>
        <echo>Skip.</echo>
    </else>
</if>
```

This works for my current purpose but I'm afraid it might break some time in the future... for example when a build is executed in path `/not/some/dir/` which is also contains the specified directory string.

Are there any more robust solutions like a `startsWith` comparison or even better a file system based check...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific `startswith` condition in native Ant, but there is a `matches` condition that takes regular expressions.

As a side note, ant-contrib is rarely necessary for most build scripts, and will often lead to unreliable code. I would strongly recommend avoiding it.

Here's a sample script to illustrate how you can use the `matches` condition with native Ant. The `test` target is, of course, just for demonstration.

```
<property name="pattern" value="^/some/dir" />

<target name="init">
    <condition property="basedir.starts.with">
        <matches pattern="${pattern}" string="${basedir}" />
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="execute" depends="init" if="basedir.starts.with">
    <echo message="Executing" />
</target>

<target name="test">
    <condition property="dir1.starts.with">
        <matches pattern="${pattern}" string="/some/dir/" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="dir2.starts.with">
        <matches pattern="${pattern}" string="/some/dir/to/my/project/" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="dir3.starts.with">
        <matches pattern="${pattern}" string="/not/some/dir/" />
    </condition>

    <echo message="${dir1.starts.with}" />
    <echo message="${dir2.starts.with}" />
    <echo message="${dir3.starts.with}" />
</target>
```